# How do I print out every string in a char** to printf()?

Tags: c, while-loop, printf, command-line-arguments, c-strings

I have a main() routine which takes in all the command line arguments as a 'char **'.  How do I display every one of the arguments in the console using printf()?

Thanks!

Comment: You do it in a loop?

Comment: You know the first argument to `main()` is the number of strings in the `char**`, right?

Comment: Even easier, `argv[argc]` is a null pointer. It's just like iterating through a string.

Comment: Fred, I didn't realize that, now everything is simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean command line arguments then I think the simplest approach looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    while ( *argv ) printf( "%s\n", *argv++ );
}
```

Take into account that ( C Standard, 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup, p.N2)

> — If the value of argc is greater than zero, **the string pointed to
>   by argv[0] represents the program name**; argv[0][0] shall be the null
>   character if the program name is not available from the host
>   environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
>   pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program
>   parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy. Please use google or use this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int i=argc;
        while((i--)>1)
            printf("%s\n",argv[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```